# Prevent Javascript calling Typescript without error

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

Suppose, I am writing a library with Typescript. There is a function with following signature-

```
function check(value: "YES"|"NO"): boolean
```

So, when this function is called from other typescript files with values other than "YES" or "NO", there will be a compilation error. But if called from a Javascript file, there will be no error, as Javascript do not has the type information. I can check for invalid values inside my function and throw errors. But then the type safety provided by Typescript seems only an illusion to me.

What should I do in this case as a library developer? Go with pure javascript? What did the teams like Angular do?

Comment: You should do what you think best. This question has no *objective* answer, and so is off-topic for SO. *"...answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions..."*

Comment: I am not to familiar with Typescript but from what I understand, it gets converted into pure javascript at compilation time. That said, if you deliver compiled code instead of typescript code, it should work as intended? I am also holding on to this point, typescript is meant to help you code by putting on restrictions and preventing errors. The JS it compiles into is what actually goes into the product. So, since you cannot force the society to use typescript you cannot really on typescript to keep your code 'error free'.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Should I ask this on programmers?

Comment: Typescript doesn't have run-time checks, so if you plan to use your library as non-typescript and parameters check is important for it, make sure you include those restrictions in the function itself, because it's no longer Typescript domain.

Comment: @Gulshan: Possibly, I don't know what's on-topic for Programmers. I'd check their [on-topic page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @dfsq: The more I think about it, the more I think there is an objective answer, and it's contained in your comment. E.g., you can rely on this stuff internally in the lib, but all the public-facing APIs have to do their own validity checking.

Comment: Is it an option to run the JS program you are calling this function from through TS?

Answer (score 2):

This is the difference between build-time (compile-time) and run-time error checking. TypeScript only helps you with Build-time checks. Providing a TypeScript Definition File with your library will help you users get meaningful compile-time errors when they use your lib incorrectly.

If your lib is being consumed by JavaScript directly, you'll have no build-step to notify the user, and you'll have to resort to run-time messaging. If file size is not an issue, I'd suggest throwing a meaningful error message:

```
function (check) {
  if (check != "YES" && check != "NO") 
    throw new Error("Invalid Check Value: " + check);
  ...
}
```

If you are concerned about file size, probably best to simply no-op on invalid calls. Or have some sort of sensible default. It will depend on your situation.

You could also consider a "debug" build of your library that provides error messages, but exclude them from the minified release build.